# RGB 565 format on Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, opengl-es

In the sample code, RIM treats bitmaps as if they are in [565 RGB format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monochrome_and_RGB_palettes#16-bit_RGB), instead of the usual [8888 ARGB format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model#The_32-bit_RGB_representation) you get on desktops,

For example:

```
net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap bitmap =
  net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "BlackBerry.png" );
GLUtils.glTexImage2D(gl, 0, GL10.GL_RGB, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, bitmap, null);
```

The bitmap on disk, however, is 8888 ARGB -- why does the sample code use 565 RGB, and can I use 8888 ARGB, 4 bytes per pixel, instead of this 2 bytes per pixel?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it, I think.

```
GLUtils.glTexImage2D(gl, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmap, null);
```

That works, even though it looks like it shouldn't (it seems the function automatically treats  `Bitmap` as R5G6B5 if needed, or A8R8G8B8 if needed.)

There's also glTexImage2D (http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/khronos/opengles/GL10.html#glTexImage2D(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, java.nio.Buffer)) which is a bit lower level than the GLUtils version.

Comment: Just be sure that it works on the device the right way too.  When dealing with OpenGL in particular, the device does not behave the same way as the simulator.